# Back/Up Arrow not working when using navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

The back or up button is not working when using a navigation drawer. The icon changes from a hamburger (having set the top level destinations) but both open the navigation drawer. I want the back/up arrow to go back in the stack.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DrawerLocker {

```
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navView;
private Toolbar toolbar;

private NavController navController;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;


private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //configure drawer layout
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navView = findViewById(R.id.drawer_navigation_view);

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.scenarioListFragment,
            R.id.tokenListFragment, R.id.settingsFragment,R.id.historyFragment)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState == null ) {
        navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.drawer_menu_scenario);
        toolbar.setTitle("Scenarios");
    }
}
```

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wv5VFEcnb-8), which made it seem sort of simple, but it is referring to Kotlin and my code is not far off.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219768/toolbars-back-button-not-working-when-using-with-navigation-drawer) covers a similar challenge as well, though in Kotlin I tried adding a setNavigationOnClickListener and put a logd statement in it. It never got fired, but the solution itself seemed like it shouldn't be necessary.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030589/how-to-make-up-button-go-back-instead-of-opening-navigation-drawer) seems to have cover the same issue but there are no answers. One of the responses says to setupActionBarWithNavController, which I have:

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

This function has a lot of overloads and I've tried a number of them, but they seem to cause me to lose the set of top level destinations (hamburger icon for multiple fragments) and undue my the navigation which is working.

I tried to follow [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), but it only seemed to step me back from where I was. This call:

```
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
            new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                    .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                    .build();
```

Seems to replace the topLevelDestinations and use the navController.getGraph(), but since I have multiple ones, I have been referencing the [fragments themselves](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration).

I did [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525227/navigation-drawer-hamburger-menu-working-but-back-arrow-opens-the-drawer) about this problem previously but it was clear to me I did not explain it well (answers addressed how to pop back and not why the back arrow was not working). I would have deleted it but people did answer and the guidance SO provided was that I should not delete it in that case. I am sorry if I caused confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues:

1. As per the [Add a navigation drawer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer):

> When using `NavigationUI`, the top app bar helpers automatically transition between the drawer icon and the Up icon as the current destination changes. You don't need to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

So you must remove all of your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` code.

2. As per the [Setting up the Action bar documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar):

> override `onSupportNavigateUp()` to handle Up navigation:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,
            R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Note that your `if (savedInstanceState == null)` is also unnecessary if you've [included an `android:label` on your destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar) and are using `setupWithNavController`.

Comment: I have one area of my app in which I need the drawer and the back/up button to be disabled and not visible. How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: That seems like precisely what the `OnDestinationChangedListener` was built for as per the [Listen for navigation events documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events)

Comment: Removing the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` code did it for me. In the process of migrating I didn't realize this wasn't needed any more and now the back arrow works.